# mobile responsive css, inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have 2 buttons on the page style as `inline-block`, but when shrinking the window size smaller, those two buttons become one on the top and one on the bottom.
What I wanted is to change the 2 buttons smaller together, don't want to have two separated buttons.
here is my code.

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" class="button1">button1</a>
   <a href="#" class="button2">button2</a>       
</div>

    a{
        display:inline-block;
        text-indent:-999px;
        padding:1em 3em;
        background:red;
    }

    .button2{
        background:blue;
    }
```

Online sample
http://jsfiddle.net/7NaDg/

How can I make those two buttons smaller consistently when the window size gets small? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the max-width of the div.box then set the button width as 50%.

```
.box {
    max-width:12em;
}

a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-indent:-999px;
    width:50%;
    padding:1em 0;
    background:red;
}

.button2{
    background:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yvdM/4/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid wrapping these buttons:

```
div.box { white-space:nowrap; }
```

To make them always fit:

```
a { max-width:50%; box-sizing:border-box; }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7NaDg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the position of the second a element to position absolute

```
.button2{
    background:blue; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:5px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7NaDg/